# How to trigger event when specific column is hovered? mui

Tags: javascript, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I've created a **lock** icon that should appear when hovered over, similar to the default **menu** icon behavior. Although my code works, there's a slight delay in showing the lock icon (see video). I expected both icons to display simultaneously.

**video**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MY3tbmJFoh8CesBNL1jYMUBoCAEAR9UW/view?usp=sharing

---

I've tried various approaches, including using the `renderHeader` prop, but encountered issues with the **lock** icon not showing when hovering over the **menu** icon (three vertical dots icon). However, I'd like to stick with my current implementation, as it seems close to my goal.

If possible, could you help me investigate how to make them display simultaneously when the header is hovered? I'm also open to any alternative suggestions. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**App.tsx**

```
const App = () => {
    const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState<boolean>(false)

    const columns = [
        ratioColumn({ isHovered }),
        // Other columns...
    ]

    return (
        <DataGrid
            columns={columns}
            onColumnHeaderOver={(params) => setIsHovered(params.field === 'ratio')}
            onColumnHeaderOut={() => setIsHovered(false)}
        />
    )
}
```

**ratioColumn.tsx**

```
const ratioColumn = ({
    isHovered,
}: RatioColumnProps) => {
    ... more code here

    return {
        field: 'ratio',
        renderHeader: () => {
            return (
                <Box sx={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>
                <IconButton
                    sx={{
                      opacity: isHovered ? 1 : 0,
                    }}
                >
                    <HttpsIcon />
                </IconButton>
                Long Text Sample
                </Box>
            )
        },
        // other props
    }
}
```

> I this can be resolved with some JavaScript tricks, so I also tagged it with JavaScript.